# ASP.NET Core - How to Cache student data using Redis in ASP.NET Core Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

In my ASP.NET Core-6, I am implementing Dapper to query data from the DB using Dapper.

I have this code:

**Implementation:**

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
{
    public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _redis;

    public StudentRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get { return new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")); }
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Students>> GetAllStudents()
    {
        using IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection;
        try
        {
            string sQuery = @"SELECT * FROM Students";
            dbConnection.Open();
            var listaSql = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Students>(sQuery);
            return (listaSql);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;
    public StudentsController(
    IStudentsRepository StudentRepository
        )
    {
        _studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetAllStudents")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetQueryStudentAsync()
    {
        var result = await _studentRepository.GetAllStudents();
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

I am using this Package:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis
```

Apart from retrieving the student record from the DB, which I have successfully done.

From my code above, how do I cache the student records using Redis after retrieving the data?

Comment: I have a few questions for you: 1st: why redis? You can do that in repository level or in request level. Either one would work. the first implementation I would make would be some memory cache that works file 90% of the times.

Comment: Via a hyper vm, but like Felipe said, why?

Comment: @FelipeEsteves - I am using Redis so that the Student Records retrieve from DB using Dapper will be cached, and easily and quickly retrieved next time. Any assistance?

Comment: If you need to cache the response only I would recommend you to use [ResponseCache] attribute. That would make the cache implementation far away easier than using reds. ASP.Net Core does that out of the box. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-7.0 . Redis works like a parallel database, so you'd use that for real complex stuff. A simple cache like that Response Cache would do the trick.

Comment: Also I would use Dapper for complex queries that need performance. Writing plain SQL like that in the code can cause you a lot of trouble. In this case, you can use Entity Framework instead.